# Sum and For loop together in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to know how many common characters in the given sets.

```
Input: J = "aA", S = "aAAbbbb"
Output: 3
```

In the python solution for this as follows:

```
lookup = set(J)
return sum(s in lookup for s in S)
```

I have following solution in Swift it works, but it looks too wordy. I want to learn shorter way of it.

```
class Solution {
    func checkInItems(_ J: String, _ S: String) -> Int {
        let lookup = Set(J) ;
        var sy = 0;
        for c in S
        {
            if lookup.contains(c)
            {
               sy += 1;                
            }
        }        
        return sy;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to know how often any of the input characters appear in the string you're searching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a small variation of [Sh_Khan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709071/1187415) you can use `reduce` to
count the number of matching elements without creating an intermediate
array:

```
func checkInItems(_ J: String, _ S: String) -> Int {
    let lookup = Set(J)
    return S.reduce(0) { lookup.contains($1) ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
}
```

In Swift 5 there will be a `count(where:)` sequence method for this purpose,
see [SE-0220 `count(where:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
class Solution {
  func checkInItems(_ J: String, _ S: String) -> Int {
    let lookup = Set(J)
    return S.filter { lookup.contains($0) }.count
  }
}
```